# Webkit CSS Reset?

Tags: css, webkit

I know there's a few CSS Reset tools out there, Eric's and Yahoo's to name 2.
However, when I'm using certain tags (I think they're called tags?) such as "li" and "ul", I get some extras in the User Agent Stylesheet. Some of these are:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;  
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;  
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;  
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;  
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

I'm wondering if there's a reset stylesheet out there that deals -webkit etc?
I have searched for one, but with now luck.

Comment: Could you show an example of how these "extra rules" are affecting the display of those tags? *(hint: they aren't).*

Comment: I can't show how they're affecting it right now, since I'm in the process of moving my domain, but the "-webkit-padding-start" was affecting my layout, until it was overwritten.

Comment: Did you use `padding: 0;`? The different with the `padding-start` and co is that they are text-direction aware... But they overwrite each other.

Comment: This can be very annoying with -webit-text-resize. There are definitely a handful off webkit properties that should be reset. Chrome's incredibly intrusive yellow bg to form fields also comes to mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While these styles are applied by Webkit, they are over-ruled by `margin: 0; padding: 0;` located in the CSS resets. You don't have to worry about them.

*Note: Although Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.116 m) Developer Tools does not display the user agent styles with strikethrough, the computed styles do reflect that explicit `margin` and `padding` values override.*

Comment: `margin` and `padding` do not override these styles in my experience.

Comment: @Jakobud: Agreed. Are myself having problem with fieldsets just now where that darn webkit css is doing its own thing. Having to reset all those -webkit-xxx- should be unnecessary. Also, this should not be marked as an answer as it is incorrect.

Comment: Edit to myself as I noticed that margin and padding do overwrite correctly, but the developer tools in Chrome do not show this as it normally does by crossing out what is not in effect. Might be a bug in the Chrome tools...?

Comment: I have to add additional rules to normilze.css to override the user agent when it comes to -webkit-xxx-

Comment: Why aren't they visibly marked out in Safari than? ... stackoverflow.com/questions/17516655/is-my-css-properly-reset

Comment: I incorrectly downvoted this: what Chrome Developer tools shows is confusing and misleading in terms of its vendor prefixed items. Make sure you have set margin: 0; padding: 0; on both the ul and li (but especially the ul). This should fix it even though what dev tools says is wrong.

Answer (score 13):

Acctually if you are working with 
    `<ul>`  in your markup the 
reset `margin: 0,  padding: 0;` do not overwrite the `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`

I solved the problem by adding to my reset file a

```
ul {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `li` and `ul`, and found the following solution: in my CSS, I had an attribute for the `li` of my list which was `display: inline`. I replaced it with `float: left` and it works. I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

If `user agent stylesheet` is being called, it is because the property that is called for / needed was not properly defined in your css stylesheet.

Error check your CSS using a tool like [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) and fix any problems that might be detected before trying workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same problem with my `<h3>` tag. I tried setting `margin:0;`, but it didn't work.

I found that I was habitually commenting out lines in my css by using `//`. I never noticed it because it hadn't caused any problems before. But when I used `//` in the line before declaring `<h3>`, it caused the browser to skip the declaration completely. When I traded out `//` for `/**/` I was able to adjust the margin.

Moral of this story: Always use proper commenting syntax!