# Is my CSS properly reset?

Tags: css, webkit

Please note, I'm only interested in making micro changes, not applying entire CSS resets.  I want to figure things out for this particular element.

Regarding below:

Everything looks well and I recognize the CSS as I created it.  The only thing that does not make sense, is the style rule under `Basic Style Rules`.  I am not familiar with the 4 webkit-margin rules.

Should they be reset to 0 some how?

What are they for?

I did not set these and they are not in the single CSS file I use.

**ut_but_new (just the button)**

[image: ut_but_new]

**CSS**

[image: css]

Comment: Please take look at **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721966/webkit-margin-adds-unwanted-margin-on-texts)**, and **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290777/webkit-css-reset)**

Comment: According to those links, they should be over-written, however I don't see them crossed out, as I thought that Safari would do this to let you know they have been over-ridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the default margins for the -webkit styles.

You can override them using the margin:0;

Comment: seems to be the consensus...but if you look at the CSS I posted, I do have margin set to 0, yet I don't see the webkit styles crossed out as I do other attributes which are over-written.

Comment: What is the program you are viewing your styles in? I like to inspect my rendered styles in a web browser using firebug. You will notice that as you inspect each element that those "Basic Style Rules" will not show.

Answer (score 0):

These rules are what the browser falls back to by default if no CSS is defined.

In this case, the browser is webkit based, so they have the -webkit prefix.

If everything looks fine, there is no reason to override them.